# Websphere Portal 7 - WebDav theme deployment is terribly slow

Tags: websphere-portal

We are trying to deploy the theme to the Websphere Portal server 7.0. But the WebDav connection is terribly slow. The maximum speed we get is 0.4 Kbps.

With this speed, its almost becoming impossible to copy the entire theme. Any pointers to what went wrong here?

Note: We tried BitKinex and AnyClient to upload.

Server info:

IBM WebSphere Portal 7.0

Build Level: wpnext_528_01 2010-08-18 17:49

Feature Pack: none

Comment: I typically use AnyClient and never experience this kind of problem. Are you experiencing any other performance problems when accessing the Portal? It's my guess that something in the network is slowing down your bandwidth.

Comment: I am deploying on my local server. I think there may be some firewall/anti virus check slows down the process.